# get ros2 version in C++

Tags: ros, ros2, rclcpp

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Are there any #define to know which version of ROS2 I'm using in C++ source?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/336640/get-ros2-version-in-c++/) by [galou](https://answers.ros.org/users/14171/galou/) on ROS Answers with karma: 265 on 2019-11-01

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

There are no defines in C/C++ out of the box.

That being said if your package depends on `ros_environment` the following environment variables are set: `ROS_VERSION` (which is either `1` or `2`), `ROS_DISTRO` (e.g. `dashing` or `melodic`), etc.

You can use either to set compiler definitions in your package to be used in conditionals.

If you need more fine grain control you can also use the exact version number of each dependency (e.g. https://github.com/ros2/rmw_cyclonedds/pull/51).

---

Originally posted by [Dirk Thomas](https://answers.ros.org/users/2575/dirk-thomas/) with karma: 16276 on 2019-11-02

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2